# ExtJs 3.x scrolling ListView programmatically

Tags: javascript, extjs3

The code below is straight out of the 3.x examples.

Can anyone help me with the script that moves the listview body, as if it was being scrolled?

Thanks,
Josh

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['name', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'}],
        data : [{"name":"dance_fever.jpg","size":2067,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/dance_fever.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"gangster_zack.jpg","size":2115,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/gangster_zack.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"kids_hug.jpg","size":2477,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/kids_hug.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"kids_hug2.jpg","size":2476,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/kids_hug2.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"sara_pink.jpg","size":2154,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/sara_pink.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"sara_pumpkin.jpg","size":2588,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/sara_pumpkin.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"sara_smile.jpg","size":2410,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/sara_smile.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"up_to_something.jpg","size":2120,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/up_to_something.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"zack.jpg","size":2901,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/zack.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"zacks_grill.jpg","size":2825,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/zacks_grill.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"zack_dress.jpg","size":2645,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/zack_dress.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"zack_hat.jpg","size":2323,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/zack_hat.jpg"}
                ,{"name":"zack_sink.jpg","size":2303,"lastmod":1265631056000,"url":"images\/thumbs\/zack_sink.jpg"}]
    });

    var listView = new Ext.list.ListView({
        id      : 'listview',
        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        emptyText: 'No images to display',
        columns: [{
            header: 'File',
            width: .45,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },{
            header: 'Last Modified',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'm-d h:i a',
            width: .3, 
            dataIndex: 'lastmod'
        },{
            header: 'Size',
            dataIndex: 'size',
            tpl: '{size:fileSize}',
            align: 'right',
            cls: 'listview-filesize'
        }]
    });

    // put it in a Panel so it looks pretty
    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
        id:'images-view',
        width:425,
        height:250,
        collapsible:true,
        resizable : true,
        layout:'fit',
        title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
        items: listView
    });
    panel.render(document.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below assumes you would like to scroll the listView down by 50pixels.

```
var listView = Ext.get('listView'); 
var listViewBody = listView.el.child('.x-list-body'); 
listViewBody.scroll('down', 50);
```